# Absolute Positioning Inside Absolutly Positioned Div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm a relatively new guy to HTML and CSS so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Anyway I can't seem to re-create this:

[image]

I am converting this mobile app into a webpage. Anyway I have a 'wrapping' to make everything centred when resizing which was my first problem but then when I did that I could not reposition the divs that are inside the wrapping when using position:absolute. I partly fixed this by using relative positioning for one of the divs but this caused me to not be able to put the relatively positioned one where I wanted it. My question: How do I arrange the icons like the image and have it not move when loaded in different resolutions and when the window is resized?

```css
 /* Body */
 #body {
   background-image: url('images/bg-img.jpg');
   font-family: Museo300-Regular, Museo700-Regular;
 }
 /* Font */
 @font-face {
   font-family: Museo300-Regular;
   src: url(Museo300-Regular.otf)
 }
 /* Nav */
 #wrapper {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* Safari */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 #home {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* Safari */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   z-index: 6;
 }
 #contact {
   position: absolute;
   top: 80%;
   left: 30%;
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /* Safari */
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   z-index: 5;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Micah Friesen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <!-- page content -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="home">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/homebttn2.png" title="Homepage (Here)" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="images/contactbttn.png" title="Contact Me, this also includes Rates" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

for both the images (containing the icons)
Here is my code^

Answer (score 0):

With the [flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you can center quite well an element, horizontally and vertically.

```
html {
        height: 100%
}

body {
        background-image: url('images/bg-img.jpg');
        font-family: Museo300-Regular, Museo700-Regular;
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
        position: relative;
}

#wrapper > div {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
}

#wrapper > div#home {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
}

#wrapper > div#contact {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        left: -150px;
        top: 10px
}
```

http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/XbWzRV?editors=110

Comment: OK, this has worked with your images but it seems that when I use mine it does not, My images end up going off to the side and inside a invisible thing. Just look at [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=24944549923384440737)

Comment: I've updated the code to set images as background: http://codepen.io/gaelb/pen/XbWzRV?editors=110 . The problem you had was the image size.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have your images (width, height, or position), so I used some temporary images and placed them offset from-center on the screen. Here's a minimal set of code to get you going with your positioning absolute-to-center.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
/* Body */
#body {
    background-image: url('images/bg-img.jpg');
    font-family: Museo300-Regular, Museo700-Regular;
}
/* Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: Museo300-Regular;
    src: url(Museo300-Regular.otf)
}
/* Nav */
#home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 6;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
#contact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 8;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body">
  <!-- page content -->
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="home">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/temp2.png" title="Homepage (Here)" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="images/temp.png" title="Contact Me, this also includes Rates" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are the margins there in the CSS and what do they do?

Comment: "position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;" puts the top-left corner of any item (rendered as a box) in the precise middle of its parent item that has position (in this case <body>). The margins are what you use to take that item and then move it away from that position. If you didn't have the margins, everything would be stacked on-top of one another. 
Use the code above and play with the margins, you'll see how it maintains position to the center of the screen, regardless of browser or device width.

Comment: Ok, what if I want the image boundaries to overlap? I'm using position:relative, I tried z-index but no avail.

Comment: Image boundaries overlapping is not a problem if the images are transparent. You would just define the clickable area of the anchor tag and give that a z-index, display: block, and positioning.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with a code snippet?

Comment: My images are not overlapping even when using z-index and relative positioning

Comment: Give the #home and #contact items the same dimensions as the image they contain. Example ( #content {width: 200px; height: 120px;} ) If you're unsure of the dimensions of the box, give it "border: 1px solid red;" also just to be certain where in-space each item is.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you will eventually want to create media queries for the different resolution break-points. In the mean time however, since it appears all of your graphical elements are relative to a center-point on the screen, you can use the following formula to position each item:

```
#itemName {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px /* Image top edge distance from center, vertically */
    margin-left: -100px; /* Image left edge distance from center, horizontally */
}
```

If you're loading different resolution images dependent on screen-width, you will need to use media query detection or javascript to properly-adjust the margins of each icon.

Comment: So why can't I just position 2 th

Comment: Q #1: Why can't I just use postion:absolute inside of a element that is positioned the same way? It makes perfect sense to me, for my needs. Q #2 Why can't I use relative positioning and z-index to get the images to overlap?

Comment: What's the question and why was this voted down? This works for block-level elements inside a relatively positioned container. If you want to position your items relative to the center-point, this formula is valid.

Comment: z-index is fine to use to make sure the items don't get overlapped.

Comment: I can't vote anything down yet, so I have no idea. My question is could I create another 'wrapper' and div and use absolute positioning because it works with one absolutely positioned element in the wedge.

Comment: You would use position:relative on your #wrapper, or whichever parent element you would want to position your individual icons based-on.

Comment: You can absolutely position anything (absolute to-the-parent). So, if the parent of any of your items is the body, or #wrapper container that fills the body, then you can position any of the child elements based on that.

Comment: If I used that on my wrapper would it move off the center of the page when I resize the window or when someone on a different resolution computer views it?

Comment: No, because it's positioned relative to the center point of the screen, then marginally adjusted based on the image size. Screen width won't affect it at all.

Comment: If I use my code and just change the positioning to relative will that be good or do I have to add the margins that you mentioned earlier?